# Is there a way to make a multi core/cpu system combine its threads and emulate a smaller thread but faster processor?

Tags: partitioning

I have a program that is dependent on the single core efficiency of a CPU.

I know a server can emulate multuple different systems at once, dividing its threads to each system. I am wondering if a server can "combine" threads to emulate a more powerful CPU?

Comment: I don't understand (nothing new for me). Servers run more than one OS with virtual APP software (including for this post) VMware ESX.  A workstation can do the same thing.  ----- posted from my Linux VM

Comment: Im asking if its possible to make a server simulate a faster CPU by combining its cores/threads.

Comment: short answer, No. Both the hardware and software designs isolate threads from each other, so they need to be responsible for self-contained units of work.